# Would it be possible to use light to transfer physical object (nanoparticle) from one place to another?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, photons

I know that light has momentum and it has been used to pick up nanoparticles. But I am thinking, is it possible for us make a pouch of light to carry a very small object from one place to another. The transfer should cover a large distance.

Comment: Does it have to be a pouch? What distance are you hoping to cover? Optical tweezers can carry something a tiny distance, but the technology to carry a particle any distance requires a good deal of optical alignment and calibration. While not impossible, it would be very difficult to create something that could physically move a nanoparticle over a distance of several kilometers.

Comment: You cannot "carry" anything with photons, since this would require those thing to travel at the speed of light. But you can _push_ thing with photons. This is the mechanism behind, e.g., stellar winds and solar sails.

Comment: Optical tweezers http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_tweezers

Comment: Seems clear to me what the question is asking; any one of the close-voters mind explaining what is unclear?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what you mean by a "pouch" of light. However, yes it is possible to move very small objects using light.

Light can be used to manipulate micron-sized particles by a technique known as [Optical Tweezers](http://physicscentral.com/explore/action/tweezers.cfm).

Light is refracted as it passes through a transparent or translucent object. Light carries momentum so there is a change of momentum which results in a force on the particle in the opposite direction. Particles are deflected towards the most intense part of the beam of light, and can be trapped at a focus. Moving the focus of the beam moves the particle.

Very small reflective particles can also be pushed by bouncing light off them.